# I am trying to list the upper or lower vowels, and I am not sure if the rest of the command is right

Tags: unix

In Unix
What command would you give to list all English-language words that are exactly 5 characters long and that begin with an upper or lower-case vowel (‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’, or ‘y’), have a lower-case ‘t’ in the middle position, and end with a lower-case ‘s’?

I have used this command

```
grep '^[t].[AEIOUY].[aeiouy]..[s]$' /usr/share/dicst/words
```

it says you need to list Advent

I also tried this one

```
grep '^[aeiouy].*[AEIOUY]\|[AEIOUY].*[aeiouy].[t].s$' /usr/share/dicst/words
```

none of them work I don't know what is the wrong in my answer

Comment: `Advent` is 6 characters long and does not have `t` in the middle position.  Why would you want that in the output?

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output. Don't post them as comments or images but edit and include them to your original question. As sucn your question is not understandable.

Comment: It seems like the regex you want is just `^[AEIOUY].t.s$`

Comment: I need to the upper or lower-case vowel

Comment: Is this an assignment or a interview test question?

Answer (score 0):

With dictionary taken from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wchargin/8927565/raw/d9783627c731268fb2935a731a618aa8e95cf465/words

```
grep -Eo '([[:space:]]|^)[aeiouyAEIOUY][A-Za-z][t][A-Za-z][s]([[:space:]]|$)' /usr/share/dicst/words

Estes
Oates
Yates
altos
antes
antis
autos
iotas
oaths
```

Search for a space or a start of line (^) then a lowercase or uppercase vowel, any upper or lowercase letter, a t, any upper or lowercase letter, a lowercase s and finally a space or end of line ($)

Comment: it says unnecessary  flags /options

Comment: Could be the version of grep. I am using GNU grep version 2.20

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-o` switch of the `grep` command:

```
grep <some switches> "expression" "line" (without -o)
```

means: show me the entire lines, which contain the expression, according to the mentioned switches.

```
grep -o <some switches> "expression" "lines"
```

means: show me only the expressions.